# How to put double quotes for every array element in json with perl

Tags: arrays, json, perl

Please help me how to add double quotes to each element for the following JSOn:

```
$new_constraint='{categoryIds:[0c5401a4-7d96-44f8-a229-7403453512e8],enforcedAt:'.$availableAtVar.',enforcedUntil:'.$availableUntilVar.'}';
```

Finally it should look like bellow:

```
{"categoryIds":["0c5401a4-7d96-44f8-a229-7403453512e8"],"enforcedAt":"2007-22-08.00:00:000","enforcedUntil":"2007-22-08.00:00:000"}
```

Comment: But that isn't valid JSON.  Can you fix the code that is producing broken JSON instead?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just produce valid JSON in the first place?

E.g.

```
use JSON::MaybeXS;
...
my $new_constraint = encode_json({
    categoryIds   => ['0c5401a4-7d96-44f8-a229-7403453512e8'],
    enforcedAt    => $availableAtVar,
    enforcedUntil => $availableUntilVar,
});
```

This way you don't have "almost JSON" that you need to fix up later.